# Unable to connect to Greenplum Database using user other than gpadmin

Tags: greenplum

I am following this tutorial: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4340/admin_guide/client_auth.html
I have created user abc as superuser.
I have added following line in pg_hba.conf.

```
# IPv6 local connections:
   #
   host     all         all            0.0.0.0/0      password
   local    all         abc            127.0.0.1/28   password
   local    all         gpadmin         ident
   host     all         gpadmin         127.0.0.1/28    trust
   host     all         gpadmin         10.*.*.*/32       trust
   host     all         gpadmin         ::1/128       trust
   host     all         gpadmin         fe80::*****/128       trust
   local    replication gpadmin         ident
   host     replication gpadmin         samenet       trust
```

In postgresql.conf, I have added listen_addresses = '*' and reloaded the config by gpstop -u but still its not working. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: And what is the error message you get?

Comment: The issue is resolved. The issue was with IP address. I have added single IP instead of IP subnet.

Comment: You really should add new entries to the bottom of the pg_hba.conf file and that is why it didn't work.  The file is read from top to bottom and uses the first match found.  Secondly, use "md5" instead of "password".  md5 is encrypted password.  I realize this is just for learning but you are safer using md5.  So, at the bottom of the file, use "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" and then you can add a user which will be authenticated by encrypted password.

Comment: Thanks Sir, will keep that in mind..